# Python 2.7: GoTo "Next" if some condition is met

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to know if there is an elegant way to create a GoTo LABEL structure with Python such as it is possible on Visual Basic. I have read that it kind of depends on case to case, but let's assume that I have a loop like the following (executable):

```
for i in range(0,10):
    print "LOOP", i, "- DO SOMETHING ALL TIMES"
    print "LOOP", i, "- DO SOMETHING SOME TIMES"
    print "LOOP", i, "- DO SOMETHING ELSE ALL TIMES"
    print ""
```

What I would like to know is if it's possible to skip the middle instruction, namely `print "LOOP", i, "- DO SOMETHING SOME TIMES"`, with a construction like the following that (badly simulating the Visual Basic syntaxis) should allow the script to skip the instruction "do something some times" if i is equal to  3:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    print "LOOP", i, "- DO SOMETHING ALL TIMES"
    if i == 3: (GoTo SECONDPART)
    print "LOOP", i, "-DO SOMETHING SOME TIMES"
    SECONDPART:
    print "LOOP", i, "-DO SOMETHING ALL TIMES"
```

I know that I could write `if i != 3:` and indent the instruction "do something some times", but I'd really like to know if possible to have (or himitate) the GoTo structure of other languages. Thanks a lot, I hope it's clear (if not don't hesitate to ask!)

Comment: The first script is executable as it's all written in Python, while the second is NOT cause contains parts of syntaxis from Visual Basic.

Comment: This is a question being asked over and over again. And always, the answer is no, don't use goto even if available.

Comment: No, Python has no goto nor an elegant way to fake it.

Comment: Wow guys, I'm new to Stack Overflow but I'm just thinking, how can a person learn something if you answer such things as "don't use goto even if available" and vote down questions just for fun? Give an explanation at least, for what I think indenting hundred lines of code is less convenient than using a GoTo statement that verifies exactly the same condition and behaves exactly the same way, I really don't see the point of being so adverse when something is not possible or convenient (again, without at least explaining WHY to the beginner) :/

Comment: No self-respecting programming language (except maybe very low-level) should have a `goto`. If you think it is too much work to indent the lines use a better editor or think about putting that part of code in a new function.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ The "case against goto" is well-known CS litterature : http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD02xx/EWD215.html

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers, this is what I consider to be a constructive answer/comment with a complete explanation of the problem.

Comment: @Matthias I have heard about this but never understood precisely why, since I'm a non-expert programmer and noticed that if I write "if this then this" or "if this goto that" was apparently the same thing.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ : I learned the hard way what "goto hell" really means ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you  might find that for a decent amount of situations, well placed if statements (without an else) can work well.

For example, with your example

```
for i in range(0,10):
    print "LOOP", i, "- DO SOMETHING ALL TIMES"
    if i != 3: 
       print "LOOP", i, "-DO SOMETHING SOME TIMES"
    print "LOOP", i, "-DO SOMETHING ALL TIMES"
```

Comment: Note that the `<>` syntax has been deprecated for years, if not decades, and has finally disappeared in Python 3.

Comment: Yeah I know in my example I could have done this, but I just wanted to know if there's any other work around than indenting tons of lines of code if some conditions are met. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ : yes: put this code into a function (and more probably into a set of functions) and just call the function. Goodbye "tons of lines of code", hello ReadableCode.

Comment: @gerrit I keep on forgetting which one is deprecated and which one isn't

Answer (score 0):

There is no `goto` in python. It even was easter egg in the past (that they will introduce `goto` to python), but it never happened and will never happen. `goto` construct is ugly itself, and most languages keep it just because they started with it (and they started with it, because everybody did so)

Answer (score 0):

You can with perverse manipulation of the runtime, but for what gain? I use goto in C (burn me on a stake) but the use case is severly limited.

In this case you would actually gain a extra line of code for no good reason.